# SSRS and Power BI report server on same server?

Tags: sql-server, reporting, powerbi-report-server

Can we install Power BI and SSRS on Windows Server 2019 without having issues?

Does SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition with Software Assurance get Power BI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we install powerbi and SSRS on windows server 2019 without having issues?

Yes, though it's typically best practice to keep different servers decoupled. But you can actually integrate the two: [Power BI Report Server Integration (Configuration Manager)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/power-bi-report-server-integration-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16).

> Does SQL server Enterprise edition 2019 with software assurance get powerbi?

That's a licensing question which we're unable to answer here. Please discuss with your SQL Server vendor.

Comment: thank you , will discuss with our sql server vendor